# Smallworld Sorcerer abilities explained

Tags: small-world

Played Smallworld for the first time today. My son played as the Sorcerers and we couldn't figure out exactly how to interpret his abilities, even after reading the rules.

It says that the Sorcerer's abilities are, for each opponent, they get to replace 1 of the opponent's tiles for a Sorcerer. Sounds simple, right? Well, pretend I'm the Trolls.

What if I have a Troll region with 5 Troll tiles on it? Well he puts down 1 Sorcerer tile on that region and takes away 1 Troll. Now that region has 1 Sorcerer and 4 Trolls on it.

- Who gets the coins for that region at the end of their turn? The Sorcerers or the Trolls, both, neither?
- Can my 4 Trolls now attack his 1 Sorcerer on that region?
- Can he, at the end of his turn, deploy more Sorcerers to the region?

I couldn't find anywhere in the rules where this was covered. Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You missed an important part of the sorcerer rules: they can only use their power on a region that contains just a single opponent piece. From [the rulebook](https://ncdn1.daysofwonder.com/smallworld/en/img/sw_rules_2015_en.pdf):

> The token your Sorcerers replaces must be the only race token in its Region (A single Troll token with its Troll's Lair is considered alone for this purpose; likewise for a Race token in a Fortress or on a Mountain, these markers provide no protection to a lone Race token) and that Region must be adjacent to one of your Sorcerers'.

So all your questions don’t really apply, because the sorcerer’s ability cannot create a region with 2 different races in it. After using its power, there will be a single sorcerer token in the region, and the region will belong to the sorcerers like any other region they have.

Comment: Note that this does make Sorcerers good against Trolls (or Bivouac, or Bivouac Trolls on a mountain space!) as the extra defense is negated. Only the number of creature tokens matter for the Sorcerers abilities. But remember to remove the lairs or other bonus tokens afterwards. Sorcerers don't get to keep them.